# How get Admin credentials? I am the Admin already

Tags: windows, cmd, credentials, privileges

My new computer have Windows 8.1 64-bit Spanish version; the previous one had Windows XP and I never messed before with Credentials, Privileges, etc. In my computer there is just one user account that is marked as Administrator: "They have access to all files and programs stored in the computer". However, if I open a command-line window and execute `chkdsk` I get this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Antonio>  chkdsk
Acceso denegado porque no tiene privilegios suficientes.
Invoque esta utilidad ejecutándola en modo elevado.
```

That is: "Access denied because you have not enough privileges. Invoke this utility executing it in elevated mode". I tried to use `runas` command, but I don't understand what parameters I must give.

I get the same result when I execute `fsutil` with these options:

```
C:\Users\Antonio>  fsutil fsinfo ntfsInfo C:
Error:  Acceso denegado.
```

How can I execute these programs in my computer? TIA

Comment: This the right place to ask?  maybe... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic for SO. [su] would be the more appropriate [se] site for this question. Voting to migrate it there. Good luck.

Comment: @ficuscr: It works! Place it in an answer and I gladly select it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the 21 century and the world of UAC ;)

The following MSDN article explains how to launch cmd.exe with the needed Admin privileges.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

> 1)    Click Start, click All Programs, and then click Accessories.
>
> 2)    Right-click Command prompt, and then click Run as
>   administrator.
>
> 3)    If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that
>   the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

Comment: The description at that site said: "If your user account is a member of the Administrators group, but is not the Administrator account itself, then, by default, the programs that you run only have standard user permissions". I understand from this paragraph (and from common sense) that if your user account _IS the Administrator account itself_, this procedure should not be necessary...

Comment: @Aacini: yes, by default UAC is turned off for the built-in Administrator account.  But based on your question, you weren't testing with the built-in Administrator account, but with the account named Antonio.  By default, the built-in Administrator account is disabled.